# Why Gradle requires properly configured `repositories` closure even for offline builds?

Tags: firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to debug an issue with a **slow Gradle installation after adding a new dependency (Firebase).**

I have several entries in `allprojects.repositories` closure, something like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url 'https://internal.example.com/mvn-public/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I'd remove all of them except the one needed for Firebase and check if that speeds up the installation, but this doesn't work, due to the following issue:

When I go back to `master` before adding new dependency, and do offline build, it works fine (because I have everything on disk already) - good:

```
gradlew build --offline
```

But now, I remove all entries from `allprojects.repositories` closure and run the same command again:

```
gradlew build --offline
```

and surprisingly, I get an error telling me that it can't resolve the dependencies. It's surprising to me, because since I just built with `--offline` flag a minute ago, it should be on disk, and I don't have any wildcard dependencies that would require a network lookup for updates - all versions are hardcoded (i.e. `1.4.1`, not `1.4.*`).

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find io.requery:requery:1.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find io.requery:requery-android:1.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
...
```

Why Gradle fails to find the dependencies in the 2nd case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_cache), it seems to be on purpose

> The Gradle cache does not allow the local cache to hide problems and create other mysterious and difficult to debug behavior that has been a challenge with many build tools. This new behavior is implemented in a bandwidth and storage efficient way. In doing so, Gradle enables reliable and reproducible enterprise builds.

...

> Dependency resolution will fail if the required artifacts are not available in any repository specified by the build, even if the local cache has a copy of this artifact which was retrieved from a different repository.

However it's a bit puzzling why this happens also in `--offline` mode.